# XML child nodes are not being saved

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing some C# application for making backups and I have an issue with saving child-nodes in my XML file where I store all backup details.

File itself should look like this:

```
<backup id="0" totalParts="3" date="0" name="0" description="0">
    <backup_part id="0" mboxId="0" muid="0">HASH</backup_part>
    <backup_part id="1" mboxId="0" muid="0">HASH</backup_part>
    <backup_part id="2" mboxId="0" muid="0">HASH</backup_part>
</backup>
```

I create parent node ("backup") with following:

```
    public static XmlElement AddNewBackupNode(
        XmlDocument xmlDoc, int backupId, int totalBackupParts, 
        string backupDate, string backupName, string backupDescription)
    {
        xmlDoc.Load(Program.defaultBackupFile);
        XmlElement singleBackup = xmlDoc.CreateElement("backup");

        var reqNumericAttr = new TupleList<int, string>
        {
            { backupId, "id" },
            { totalBackupParts, "totalParts" }
        };

        var reqStringAttr = new TupleList<string, string>
        {
            { backupDate, "date" },
            { backupName, "name" },
            { backupDescription, "description" }
        };

        // TODO: remove one foreach
        foreach (var attr in reqNumericAttr)
        {
            XmlAttribute newAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute(attr.Item2);
            newAttribute.Value = attr.Item1.ToString();
            singleBackup.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);
        }

        foreach (var attr in reqStringAttr)
        {
            XmlAttribute newAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute(attr.Item2);
            newAttribute.Value = attr.Item1.ToString();
            singleBackup.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);
        }

        xmlDoc.Save(Program.defaultBackupFile);
        return singleBackup;
    }
```

and that part is working.

Then I want to add several (as many as needed) child nodes with this:

```
    public static void AddNewBackupPart(XmlDocument xmlDoc, XmlElement backup, string fileHash, int backupPartId, int mboxId, int uid)
    {
        XmlElement backupPart = xmlDoc.CreateElement("backup_part");
        backupPart.InnerText = fileHash;

        var reqAttr = new TupleList<int, string>
        {
            { backupPartId, "id" },
            { mboxId, "mboxId" },
            { uid, "uid" }
        };

        foreach(var attr in reqAttr)
        {
            XmlAttribute newAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute(attr.Item2);
            newAttribute.Value = attr.Item1.ToString();
            backupPart.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);
        }

        backup.AppendChild(backupPart);
        xmlDoc.Save(Program.defaultBackupFile);
    }
```

and that one fails so save its content to file (brand new child nodes).

I tried to run it different ways like adding 2 or 22 child nodes but it always finishes same way like on the top - with default content.

No errors or warnings are displayed whatsoever.

Any ideas what have I done wrong?

**EDIT:** this is where I call AddNewBackupPart:

```
// add new backup row to XML
XmlDocument xmlDoc = XMLparser.LoadBackupsFile(); // TODO: if above can't be done, move that line to XMLparser and Add... method
XmlElement backupRoot = XMLparser.AddNewBackupNode(xmlDoc, backupId, totalBackupParts, backupDate, backupName, backupDescription);

        // handle each file in folder
        int partId = 1;
        foreach (string fileName in FileHandler.GetAllBackupPackages())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("file: {0}", fileName);

            // generate Hash
            string fileHash = FileHandler.GenerateFileChecksum(fileName);
            Console.WriteLine("hash: {0}", fileHash);

            // add single node to XML
            XMLparser.AddNewBackupPart(xmlDoc, backupRoot, fileHash, partId, 000);

            partId++;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that call `AddNewBackupPart(...)` please ?

Comment: @aprovent I've updated code in 1st post, sorry!

Comment: @Tomas yes it is, at the top of the 1st post you can find how does XML file looks itself

Comment: @aprovent sorry but I don't undestand. Can you provide fragment you are referring to?

Comment: It would really help if you provided a [mcve] that compiled and just showed the bare minimum code required to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Your whole code is a bit messy. First it looks like you load an XML document and return it by `XmlDocument xmlDoc = XMLparser.LoadBackupsFile()` but inside `AddNewBackupNode()` you completely ignore that document and replace it by something else: `xmlDoc.Load(Program.defaultBackupFile);`. Don't do such things. It's totally confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that in `AddNewBackupNode` you do this:

```
xmlDoc.Load(Program.defaultBackupFile);
XmlElement singleBackup = xmlDoc.CreateElement("backup");
```

You then add everything to `singleBackup`, but you never add `singleBackup` to the document anywhere.

Given you can't add more than one root element to an XML document, you most likely want to add this as the child of an element that's already in the XML you load, for example:

```
xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(singleBackup);
```

As an aside, I'd strongly suggest you look at LINQ to XML - it's a much nicer API than `XmlDocument` and would let you write code that's far easier to follow than this.  It could be written more declaratively with far less code - I've included an example below, but it's not clear where most of the variables actually come from given your code is incomplete.:

```
var backupParts = FileHandler.GetAllBackupPackages()
    .Select((fileName, index) => new XElement("backup_part",
        new XAttribute("id", index + 1),
        new XAttribute("mboxId", "?"),
        new XAttribute("uid", "?"),
        FileHandler.GenerateFileChecksum(fileName)));

var backup = new XElement("backup",
    new XAttribute("id", backupId),
    new XAttribute("totalParts", totalBackupParts),
    new XAttribute("date", backupDate),
    new XAttribute("name", backupName),
    new XAttribute("description", backupDescription),
    backupParts);

var doc = XDocument.Load(Program.defaultBackupFile);

doc.Root.Add(backup);

doc.Save(Program.defaultBackupFile)
```

Comment: Funny. Exactly that part has been described as "is working"